# Oracle trigger to queue/dequeue doesn't fire

Tags: oracle, queue, oracle11g

Oracle 11g.
I have a trigger which calls a procedure. That procedure performs queue and dequeue.
When I run the procedure in sqldeveloper, it runs fine.
If I update the tables which the trigger fires off, the procedure runs fine.
If I go into the application in question and run a process which causes the trigger to fire, the procedure doesn't work. Specifically the queue and dequeue don't work because if I remove the queue/dequeue code, and instead do an insert on a table, the procedure runs fine.

So I'm thinking that maybe there's a permissions problem causing the trigger unable to execute on dbms_aq. Does anyone know how to resolve this? Is there a user account that runs the triggers which needs to be given privileges?

I don't think the problem is with the procedure because it runs fine. I'm also not passing any dynamic data from the trigger so the way I run the procedure under sqldeveloper is exactly the same way the trigger is calling the procedure.

Note: sanitized code

```
create or replace
TRIGGER mytrig
AFTER INSERT ON INVENTORY_TRANSACTION 
FOR EACH ROW 
WHEN ((NEW.CLIENT = 'abcwidgets') AND (NEW.CODE = 'Receipt'))
BEGIN
dschema.mypack.queue_receipt('abcwidgets','999','bbb','1','88');
EXCEPTION
WHEN OTHERS THEN NULL;
END;

PROCEDURE QUEUE_RECEIPT(
CLIENTID IN VARCHAR2  
, RECEIPTID IN VARCHAR2  
, SITEID IN VARCHAR2
, LINEID IN VARCHAR2
, UPDATE_QTY IN VARCHAR2
) AS
ctxHandle dbms_xmlgen.ctxHandle;
l_xml xmltype;
queueopts DBMS_AQ.ENQUEUE_OPTIONS_T;
msgprops DBMS_AQ.MESSAGE_PROPERTIES_T;
msgid RAW(16);

BEGIN
  ctxHandle := dbms_xmlgen.newContext('SELECT line_id,
user_data_4
FROM inventory
');
l_xml     := xmltype(dbms_xmlgen.getxml(ctxHandle));
 DBMS_AQ.ENQUEUE ('DSCHEMA.ABCWIDGETS_QUEUE',
  queueopts,
  msgprops,
  l_xml,
  msgid);
END QUEUE_RECEIPT;
```

Comment: Can you explain what "doesn't work" means in this particular case?  Do you get an error?  If so, what error?  If you don't get an error, what behavior are you seeing or not seeing that you expect?  Can you post some sample code that replicates the issue?

Comment: By doesn't work I mean that looking at the corresponding queue table, it remains empty. When running the procedure under sqldeveloper I don't get any errors and I see a new entry in the queue table.

Comment: I'm not sure whether posting the source code will be useful at this stage because the procedure works fine and also I'm using hard coded values to remove any possibility of invalid inputs.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could post a test case that reproduces the problem.  Otherwise, it's rather hard to guess what the problem might be.

Comment: Can you post the code of procedure and trigger?

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to fully qualify the QUEUE NAME. The queue name namespace is determined at runtime, and with no public synonym on queues, it will look in the logged in user namespace first, regardless of the procedure owner. If I had to guess, when you login to run it in sqldeveloper, it is probably as the user that owns the procedure you are calling.

Comment: Yeah, this would be in your DBMS_AQ.ENQUEUE call. I had this problem when I recently wrote a set Java/PLSQL to process XML (SAML2) messages. For example, say SAMPLE1 owns the queue named QUEUE1, then the DBMS_AQ calls would need to specify SAMPLE1.QUEUE1, or else it would look in whoever the user's objects that they were logged in as.

Comment: Ok so I qualified my queue with the schema name as in the code above. Still no good.

Comment: No errors at all if I run from sqldeveloper. I don't know how to check for errors when it's triggered from the application.

Comment: Can you login as a user in sqldeveloper and insert a dummy record?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. If I login to sqldeveloper I can update a table which causes a trigger to fire, which in turn calls the procedure which then inserts a record in the queue table.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was explained to me by a dba which was a bit over my head. There was some variable declarations in a package I was using that were declared outside the scope of a body. I moved these back into the package bodies and this caused them to start working.